# How can I stop WP media uploader from creating duplicates of my uploaded images?

Tags: theme-development, uploads, media-library

I have a setting in my theme that seeks to prevent the WP media manager upload utility from creating multiple copies of each image I upload. Apparently the latest versions of WP have changed the required settings to defeat this?

Here's the current settings I have in my theme's functions.php...

```
if(get_option('thumbnail_size_h')!==0){update_option('thumbnail_size_h', 0);}
if(get_option('thumbnail_size_w')!==0){update_option('thumbnail_size_w', 0);}
if(get_option('medium_size_h')!==0){update_option('medium_size_h', 0);}
if(get_option('medium_size_w')!==0){update_option('medium_size_w', 0);}
```

Even with these settings, I'm still getting a duplicate image every time I upload. For example, if my image filename is foo.jpg and it is 800x600 pixels, WP creates two images foo.jpg and foo-800x600.jpg

How can I force WP to not create the duplicate?

Comment: Have you disabled all the intermediate image sizes? If you set all 3 sizes to 0(Admin > Settings > Media), that should result in only one image being created on upload. I have done it on my local installation without a problem, but i have had users report it not working for them(i suspect their theme/plugin(s) is/are defining additional image sizes in those cases though - ie. `add_image_size`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should stop thumbnails from being created. If you're wanting to remove some then and unset the $size[{size}]. Following sizes are there "thumbnail","medium","large","post-thumbnail".

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced','stop_thumbs');
function stop_thumbs($sizes){
      return array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing this now. If I can use this instead of my existing get_option getter/setters, then I'd much rather...

Comment: Yep, I've commented out all my getter/setters on thumbs and replaced it with this filter and it works like a charm! Thanks again Backie!

Comment: Would it be possible to make your filter active only when the image is uploaded from "Media > Add New"? I actually want to allow the **user** to resize the image, but I don't want WP creating thumbs everytime an image is uploaded. I tried wrapping it in if($pagenow=="media-new.php") to no avail.

Comment: How to just stop some image size like Large and thumbnail but keep the medium on with Backie Function ? add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced','stop_thumbs');
function stop_thumbs($sizes){ return array();
}
How to add "thumbnail","medium","large","post-thumbnail" to that code ?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I had not enabled the large_size options...

```
if(get_option('large_size_h')!==0){update_option('large_size_h', 0);}
if(get_option('large_size_w')!==0){update_option('large_size_w', 0);}
```

Adding those settings, to my existing settings, effectively stops WP uploader from adding a copy of the image.

Answer (score 0):

As @t31os said in the comments, you don't need any code to do this. If you're just looking to disable the default sizes, you just need to set them all to "0" in Admin > Settings > Media.

Comment: I still want the end user to be able to define thumbs and use them, assuming they choose one of the thumbnail sizes when they upload the image. I just don't want WP to create the thumbs when a user is just uploading an image via Media Manager > Add New

Comment: So, recognizing that WP has to create the thumbs before it can allow you to use any of them, the ideal solution for me would be if I can apply the filter only when the user is uploading via Media Manager > Add New (and not when they are uploading from within a post).

Comment: @Scott B I don't understand what you mean by "assuming they choose one of the thumbnail sizes when they upload the image". You don't choose sizes when you upload the image--you choose them when you insert the image into a post. Both the "Media Manager > Add New" and the "New Post > Add Media > From Computer" use the same upload form, and the same process. From your comments, what I think you're trying to do is not create any additional sizes until a user tries to INSERT (not upload) their image into a post. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's essentially what I want to do, however, I don't think WP is capable of doing that. It appears that the thumbs must be created when the image is first uploaded, or they will not be created at all. So I'm ok with allowing them to be created at upload time, if the user is uploading while editing a post, but I don't want any thumbs to be created if the user uploads an image from the media manager > add new routine.

Comment: @ScottB Hmm... in that case, you can use the filter that @Backie suggested above (intermediate_image_sizes_advanced), and in the hooked function check for a field in the post collection named "_wp_http_referer". It tells you where the upload request came from. If it contains "media-new.php", you can return an empty array (which will temporarily stop thumbnail generation, but won't actually change any thumbnail settings). Otherwise, return the $sizes array untouched.